# Java Applet not showing on IE 9

Tags: java, applet, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to access a Java Applet from IE 9. I'm using this code to create the applet:

```
var attributes = {
    id:'idApplet',
    code:'some.package.PrintApplet.class',
    archive:'Applet.jar',
    codebase:'<%=base_url%>/public/jar/',
    width:400,
    height:400
};

var parameters = {
    // Some parameters
};

var version = '1.5' ;

deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
```

But I'm getting this in my .jsp page:

[image]

This is the code of my applet:

```
public class PrintApplet extends Applet{

    // Some parameters

    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Started");
    }

    public void useLocalPrinter() {
        //some actions

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you add java to add-ons plugins

Comment: @AhmadAl-Kurdi yep, in firefox I'm getting ClassNotFoundException on my .class but my jar is ok

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Be sure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show.  If there is no output at the default level, raise the level and try it again. 3) Always copy/paste error and exception output!  4) We need to know the (directory) structure of the server, and the locations of the HTML and Jar file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has this problem again, it's very simple. I was exporting my JAR from Rational Application Developer (Eclipse based) and it wasn't being recognized by the JRE. I have to use ANT to compile my JAR and the problem was gone.

The ant snippet that i used was this:

```
<project name="applet" default="jar" basedir=".">

        <property name="jar.home" value="${basedir}/lib" />
        <property name="src.home" value="${basedir}/src-applet" />
        <property name="build.home" value="${basedir}/build-applet" />
        <property name="classes.home" value="${build.home}/classes" />
        <property name="jar.name" value="wami_audio_applet.jar" />
        <property name="jar.path" value="${jar.home}/jar.name" />

        <property name="compile.debug" value="true" />
        <property name="compile.deprecation" value="false" />
        <property name="compile.optimize" value="true" />

        <path id="compile.classpath">
                <pathelement location="${basedir}/lib" />
        </path>

        <target name="all" depends="clean, prepare, jar"/>

        <target name="clean">
                <delete dir="${jar.path}" />
                <delete dir="${classes.home}" />
        </target>

        <target name="prepare">
                <mkdir dir="${build.home}" />
                <mkdir dir="${jar.home}" />
                <mkdir dir="${classes.home}" />
        </target>

        <target name="compile" depends="prepare">
                <mkdir dir="${classes.home}" />
                <javac srcdir="${src.home}" destdir="${classes.home}" debug="${compile.debug}" deprecation="${compile.deprecation}" optimize="${compile.optimize}" target="1.5">
                        <classpath refid="compile.classpath" />
                </javac>
        </target>

        <target name="jar" depends="compile" description="Make the jar">
                <jar jarfile="${jar.home}/${jar.name}" basedir="${classes.home}">
                </jar>
        </target>
</project>
```